# I am getting error for move_uploaded_file while trying to upload file on my live site

Tags: php, file

here is the error

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\Temp\php205.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (E:\inetpub\vhosts\astradingcompany.org\httpdocs) in E:\inetpub\vhosts\astradingcompany.org\httpdocs\mycar\postaddata.php on line 26

Warning: move_uploaded_file(mycar/uploads/car001.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\inetpub\vhosts\astradingcompany.org\httpdocs\mycar\postaddata.php on line 26

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php205.tmp' to 'mycar/uploads/car001.jpg' in E:\inetpub\vhosts\astradingcompany.org\httpdocs\mycar\postaddata.php on line 26

here is the code sippet

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
     {
        if((($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif') 
            || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/jpg') 
            || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/png')
            || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/jpeg')) 
            //&& ($_FILES["file"]['size'] < 20000) 
            && (in_array($extensions, $allowedextensions)))                                                                                                      
            {                                                       
             if (file_exists("mycar/uploads/". $_FILES['file']['name']))
                {
                $msg =  $_FILES['file']['name']. "<b> <font face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif' color='red'>File Already Exists</font></b>";
                header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
                }
                else
                    {
//                      $filename = "mycar/uploads/" .$_FILES['file']['name'];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "mycar/uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
//                  is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
//                  is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
//                  copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddatafile);
//                  copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filename);
```

Comment: Do you have accessibility to your php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

create a directory named uploads and assure that it is indeed writable by the server with necessary chmod priveleges.  In some instances according on server configuration the directory may need sufficient ownership as well such as www-data

Comment: uploads directory exists and how to set chmod priveleges on the server on which my site is hosted

Comment: ssh into the server and use `chmod`. You can do `man chmod` to get more info.

Comment: you may have the ability to do this with ftp as well by establishing 777 or 755 permissions

Comment: and how to ssh into the server

Comment: This is Windows Host there is no Linux permissions!

Comment: you should still be able to set an octet permission on a windows host from an ftp client like filezilla although you may need to do this though your your filemanager in your host manager

Comment: assure that you jave correct ownership of the writable directory

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [How to fix PHP upload file inherit permissions error using Windows IIS Server](http://www.howyoudo.info/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-server-upload-file-inherit-permissions-error/). Thanks to Garon, for me also same issue was there.